# Create CBR TS file from MXF file

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, video-encoding, cbr

I am looking for a way to create CBR TS file from a high bitrate MXF input file. I have tried to use ffmpeg, but apparently it doesn't do a good job of creating CBR output file so right now I am a bit clueless what I can use. I have tried to use:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mxf -copyts -c copy -muxrate 200M -f mpegts output.ts
```

I only want to add some stuffing. I have also tried to transcode the video with the command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mxf -vcodec libx264 -b:v 150M -minrate:v 150M -maxrate:v 150M -bufsize:v 140M -acodec mp2 -ac 2 -b:a 192k -f mpegts output.ts
```

but it didn't work out either.
I want the output to be completely flat. This could be done by setting the muxrate to a much higher value or by achieving completely CBR video bitrate. The ffmpeg with which I have tried is 3.2.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to achieve rather nice looking and smooth output CBR with 10-15% of stuffing. Unfortunately it requires transcoding of the original file:

```
$ffmpeg -i input.mxf \
-c:v libx264 \
-x264opts nal-hrd=cbr \
-b:v 30M -minrate:v 30M -maxrate:v 30M -muxrate 35M -bufsize:v 25M \
-acodec aac -ac 2 -b:a 128k \
-f mpegts output.ts
```

This command will create completely CBR TS from an input file. Here it is important the video bitrate (b:v) to be equal to the video maximal and minimal video bitrate, the muxrate has to be 10-15% higher than the set video bitrate including the audio bitrate and the buffsize to be around 70% of the video bitrate.